# Why I get MemoryError when I run ADF test?

Tags: python, time-series, statsmodels

[image]

This is my Timeseries:

```
                          data    z_data   zp_data
time                                              
2018-01-01 00:00:00  -0.045988       NaN       NaN
2018-01-01 00:01:00  -0.046024       NaN       NaN
2018-01-01 00:02:00  -0.044360       NaN       NaN
2018-01-01 00:03:00  -0.044722       NaN       NaN
2018-01-01 00:04:00  -0.043637       NaN       NaN
                        ...       ...       ...
2018-12-12 23:55:00  11.454639  0.088124  1.631736
2018-12-12 23:56:00  11.498422  0.935382  2.551753
2018-12-12 23:57:00  11.521695  1.251496  1.223949
2018-12-12 23:58:00  11.476974  0.244583 -0.012273
2018-12-12 23:59:00  11.480120  0.278023  0.015562
[498240 rows x 3 columns]
```

I used the Augmented Dickey-Fuller Test. This test is used to assess whether or not a time-series is stationary. but I get the MemoryError. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: You don't have enough memory to fit this array.

Answer (score 2):

`autolag` is wasting memory because it keeps all full models in memory during the lag search.

see https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues/1849

Some possible workarounds are to either

- fix the number of lags and avoid the automatic lag search, or
- limit the number of lags, set `maxlag`, that are evaluated for the lag search

This wasn't really designed with large time series in mind.

Answer (score 0):

As per [Python's documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#MemoryError):

> exception MemoryError
>
> Raised when an operation runs out of memory but the situation may still be rescued (by deleting some objects). The associated value is a string indicating what kind of (internal) operation ran out of memory. Note that because of the underlying memory management architecture (C’s malloc() function), the interpreter may not always be able to completely recover from this situation; it nevertheless raises an exception so that a stack traceback can be printed, in case a run-away program was the cause.