# Google colab keeps crashing when using adfuller()

Tags: python, crash, time-series, google-colaboratory

I've been trying to get the ADF statistic and the p-value for my time series data.
I haven't done anything rather than import the dataset and use the following code:

`from statsmodels.tsa.stattools import adfuller`
`from numpy import log`

`result = adfuller(dataset.Sales.dropna())`

The session crashes after about 3 minutes in. Then I get this message:

> 'Your session crashed after using all available RAM. '

My dataset is just 51MB. I am also using Colab's GPU.
Any ideas how to fix it ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why I get MemoryError when I run ADF test?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59846061/why-i-get-memoryerror-when-i-run-adf-test)

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to the following questions:

- [Why I get MemoryError when I run ADF test?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59846061/why-i-get-memoryerror-when-i-run-adf-test)
- [Adfuller use up all the RAM resource?](https://pystatsmodels.narkive.com/0b4cd8cW/adfuller-use-up-all-the-ram-resource)

The issue is most probably caused by the lag search due to it storing all regressions so I will suggest the same workarounds mentioned in the previous questions:

- Either limit the number of lags, set `maxlag`, that are evaluated for the lag search.

`result = adfuller(dataset.Sales.dropna(), maxlag=MAX_LAG)`

- Or fix the number of lags and avoid the automatic lag search.

`result = adfuller(dataset.Sales.dropna(), maxlag=MAX_LAG, autolag=None)`